# Find the standard deviation based on the mean and deviating sample

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

For $1000$ gnomes, $390$ of them were found to deviate from the arithmetic mean in height by no more than $1.4$ inches ($\overline{x} = 57.3$ inches). Can an approximate value for the standard deviation be determined from this data if a normal distribution is assumed?

*Attempt*
We know that $39$ percent of the gnomes do deviate from the arithmetic mean. Then, find a corresponding $z$-score, which is $z = \pm1.23$. Since I don't know the exact sample values, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I assume you found 1.23 by calculating $\Phi^{-1}(0.5+0.39)$. But this is assuming that all $390$ gnomes have heights that are all above the mean (or all below the mean). In reality, those 390 gnomes could have heights either side of the mean. It would be reasonable then to consider $\Phi^{-1}(0.5+0.195)=0.51$ (if this isn't immediately clear to you, draw the graph of a normal density function, and shade an area of $0.39$ that is symmetric around the mean). This means that $1.4$ inches approximately corresponds to $0.51$ standard deviations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and we don't even need to know what the mean of the data is.

[image]

Due to symmetry, $P(x\leq \mu + 1.4) = 0.5 + \frac{0.39}{2} = 0.695.$

$\Phi^{-1}(0.695) = 0.510\ldots.$ Therefore, $\ 0.510\ldots = \frac{\mu+1.4 - \mu}{\sigma}\implies \sigma = \frac{1.4}{0.510\ldots} = 2.7447\ldots.$